# how do i get a reference of primitive value?

Tags: javascript, types, properties, reference, primitive

```
var number = 12345;

var obj = {};
```

do something like

```
obj.look    ((((((some operator or function to get a reference of number )))))      number
```

anyway, let's think now obj has a reference to number.
so I would like to wanna do it this way.

```
obj.look = 'abc';

console.log (number); // hopefully  'abc'
```

i would like it's gonna be:

1. not method ( like obj.look()  )
2. but can refer in property ( like obj.look )

   all I'm asking is how to get a reference of primitive value.
   I believe there must be some way. please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
var number = 12345;

var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'look', {
    get() {
        return number;
    },
    set(value) {
        number = value;
    }
});

document.write(obj.look + '<br>');
obj.look = 'abc';
document.write(number);
```

Comment: How does this solve the 2nd part of the question (which makes no sense imo) : `obj.look = 'abc'; console.log (number); // hopefully  'abc'`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, i can go sleep well.and as @MinusFour mentioned, var obj = { get look(){return number;} }; will also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an object, copy that reference to another variable, mutate the object and since both variables hold a reference to the same object any changes done from one variable will also be accessible from the other variable.

Primitive values can be wrapped into objects (`new Object`) but they can not be referenced otherwise. String objects are immutable (all properties are non-configurable, non-writable) and Number objects values are not accessible either. So you can't change the value of either object.

That means when you do:

```
obj.look = 'abc';
```

You are wiping the old reference and setting up a new string there (object or primitive). `number` will still hold the old reference and will remain unchanged.

So, no. I don't think this is possible to do in Javascript.